# ImageIcon not visible

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, imageicon

I'm trying to put a `ImageIcon` on a `JLabel` but it doesn't appear in the `JFrame`. I can't find the wrong code and my console doesn't show any errors.

Here's the code:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel card;
    private JButton bBet;
    private ImageIcon c2 = new ImageIcon("./images/c2.jpg");
    private ImageIcon d2 = new ImageIcon("./images/d2.jpg");
    private ImageIcon h2 = new ImageIcon("./images/h2.jpg");
    private ImageIcon s2 = new ImageIcon("./images/s2.jpg");
    private JPanel panel;
    private int cardx1 = 250, cardy1 = 400;

    public Gui() {

        this.setTitle("Simple Blackjack");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1200, 800);
        this.setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 1200, 800);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        bBet = new JButton("Bet");
        bBet.setBounds(10, 70, 200, 35);
        bBet.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(bBet);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if (event.getSource() == bBet) {
        random = getRandom();
        addLabel(cardx1, cardy1, random);
    }


}

public void addLabel(int x, int y, int random) {

    Random r = new Random(4);
    int which = r.nextInt();

    card = new JLabel();
    card.setBounds(x, y, 166, 230);

    switch (random) {
    case 0:
        if (which == 0){
            card.setIcon(c2);
        } else if (which == 1) {
            card.setIcon(d2);
        } else if (which == 2) {
            card.setIcon(h2);
        } else if (which == 3) {
            card.setIcon(s2);
        }
        break;
    }

    panel.add(card);
    panel.repaint();


}
```

Comment: where did you add image icon?

Comment: here: private ImageIcon c2 = new ImageIcon("./images/c2.jpg"); and here: card.setIcon(c2);

Comment: Try to revalidate your panel (`panel.revalidate()`)

Comment: null layout so revalidate do nothing

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: 5) *"my console doesn't show any errors"* Once you have an URL as mentioned in tip 1, use it in `ImageIO.read(URL)` to load the image. The `read(..)` method should produce helpful information if the image cannot be found, unlike the `String` constructor for `ImageIcon` ..

Comment: @E.Reu did you attach actionlistner to any component?

Comment: @FastSnail actionlistner shouldn't be the problem because everything except the picture is working without problems.

Comment: @E.Reu image part is only work if actionperform occur.just set a background color to your jlable and see is it visible?

`card = new JLabel();
 card.setOpaque(true);
card.setBackground(Color.yellow);`

Comment: @FastSnail it looks like the labels appear but without ImageIcon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images in the project current working directory, just use `private ImageIcon d2 = new ImageIcon("images/d2.png")` without `./` 
[image]
Note: in your test code, you assume that the getRandom are always returns zero , just want to be sure that you sure about it.

Comment: I can't believe it. The wrong part was really the getRandom method O.o   Thanks for you note :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if the images are properly located then the next problem would be Random number generation.
Instead of

```
    Random r = new Random(4);
    int which = r.nextInt();
```

Use the below code to generate the random numbers

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 4);
```